# How to resolve Empty error with status code 500 axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

this is my code :

```
Express Routes:

router.route('/block')
   .post(controller.ticketBlocking);
```

```
Express Controller:

const axios = require('axios');
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const ticketBlocking = (req, res) => {

   const data  = JSON.stringify({
     source = req.body.source
   });

    const oauth = OAuth({
      consumer: {
      key: '....', //Hided the key
      secret: '....', //Hided the secret
      },
      signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      hash_function(base_string, key) {
          return crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(base_string).digest('base64');
      }
  });
  
  const request_data = {
    url: 'http://link.vvv/blockTicket',
    method: 'post',
  };
  axios({
      method: request_data.method,
      url: request_data.url,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          ...oauth.oauth.toHeader(oauth.oauth.authorize(request_data)),
      },
      data : data
  })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log(error.request);
        } else {
          console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        console.log(error.config);
      });
    
};
```

the npm package which am using is - "[oauth-1.0a](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth-1.0a)"

The problem am facing is, when i use GET method with different end point, i get an output but when ever i use POST method am getting an empty error with status code 500

I dont know where is the mistake, am using oauth1.0a for authorization, please help !

Comment: Please post the express code as well :)

Comment: Do you mean routes ?

Comment: Yeah the routes and the methods you use for them

Comment: I have updated the route, i belive these information is enough to toggle to error ?

Comment: What is the URL you use to send the POST request in axios?

Comment: there is a const "request_data" variable above the axios which hold the URL and method , do check the code and i call using the main route "v1/ticket/block" which will looks liek this ! And am using postman to check

Comment: If you do `console.log('Entire error object', error);` what will it print?

Comment: It prints Empty Error like , Error: ' '